# Retain ownership of UIImage created with UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiimage, screenshot

I am using this code to get a screenshots of the window at various different times and putting the UIImage created into an array which is passed on to another UIViewController so that they can be all displayed back in a grid. I try to release the UIImage and the memory usage never goes down ... how can I use the image here once, and retain ownership so I can release the memory once it is displayed

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.window.bounds.size);

    [self.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [imagesArray addObject:image];

    [image release];`

Comment: UIImage *scaledImage = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain]; would this help??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` returns "an **autoreleased** image object containing the contents of the current bitmap graphics context."

When you add the image to imagesArray, `NSMutableArray` does a retain on it, and
it's all you need. The memory will be released when the image is removed from the array.

You **should not** call release on image.

Answer (score 2):

I had a memory crash on UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() ... if you're creating and releasing a lot of them, you should wrap them in a fresh AutoReleasePool for each iteration. Even allowing the NSRunLoop to tick WAS NOT ENOUGH for Apple/iOS to do housekeeping on garbage lying around from this.

e.g.

```
for( ... )
{
   @autoreleasepool
   {
      UIImage* blah = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a strange UIImage memory leak using a retained UIImage image from  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() in a background thread. The problem turned out to be you should only call this function from the main thread of your application. Beware.

Comment: Per Apple docs, "This function may be called from any thread of your app." How did you confirm it should only be called from the main thread?